# Django Redirect - URL with String to URL With Slug

Tags: python, django, redirect

Not sure if I should be doing this or not... but here goes.

I have a url that looks like this:

`/deals/category/Apparel/`

I changed it to `category/Apparel` to shorten it.

but also notice the capitalized Apparel --as it is using the category name.

So I added a slug to my `Category` model and I'm trying to redirect the

`deals/category/Apparel` to `category/apparel` where the latter represents the slug

In my deals app I have this URL:

```
path('category/<str:category>', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='category', permanent=True)),
```

and which I'm trying to redirect to (in my core urls file)

```
path('category/<slug:slug>', deals_by_category, name='category')
```

My view for the `deals_by_category' looks like this:

```
def deals_by_category(request,slug):
    category_deals = Deal.objects.filter(category__slug=slug).order_by('expired','-date_added')
    category = category_deals[0].category
    return render(request, 'deals/category.html', {'category_deals': category_deals, 'category':category})
```

so when I go to `deals/category/Apparel` it is redirecting to `category/Apparel` which is not what I want... and I get an error like this:

```
Reverse for 'category' with keyword arguments '{'category': 'Apparel'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['category\\/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']
```

I guess I understand that it is looking at the category name and trying to match against a slug, but not exactly sure how to correctly redirect this with the correct format.

Comment: I believe this should be done on your http server like nginx. simply create a redirect rule like `location ~ ^/deal/category/Apparel(.*) { redirect /category/apparel$1 permanent; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
path('category/<str:category>', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='category', permanent=True)),
```

When you use `pattern_name`, Django will try to reverse the URL with the same args and kwargs, in this case `category='Apparel'`.

If you want to use the `slug` in the URL instead, then you'll have to subclass `RedirectView` and override [`get_redirect_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.RedirectView.get_redirect_url).

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class CategoryRedirectView(RedirectView):
    permanent = True

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, name=self.kwargs['category'])
        return reverse('category', kwargs={'slug': category.slug})
```

Then use your view in your URL pattern:

```
path('category/<slug:slug>', CategoryRedirectView.as_view(), name='category')
```

I wouldn't set `permanent = True` until you are sure that the redirect is working as expected. Otherwise browsers may cache incorrect redirects.

Comment: THANK YOU...this is amazing, i had gone over some of this on Django website and was getting very confused.  This is brilliant--you're a life saver